# SecurityCompass LabServer synax error on starting

Tags: python

I tried to install this server on windows 7:
    https://github.com/securitycompass/LabServer

Python is working and all aplications that I installed with this line of code are working

```
easy_install blinker cherrypy flask flask-sqlalchemy simplejson
```

When I try to run this

```
C:\LabServer-master>python app.py
```

I've got following error

```
File "app.py", line 30
print " [*] %s [%s] \"%s %s\"" % (request.remote_addr, datetime.datetime.now
().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), request.method, request.url)
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please, how to run this server?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the entire "app.py" text? At first glance this looks ok, and running this line on a local flask request prints the output with no issue.

Comment: In github link that I posted you have all the code.

Comment: What version of python are you running?

Comment: Unfortunately, print is a function in Python 3+, so this won't work.  The project itself recommends python 2.7: https://github.com/SecurityCompass/LabServer/wiki